# Showing only times within a range after freebusy google calendar API request

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

After many many tries and a whole lot of beautiful answers from other SOs, I finally managed to get the freebusy output with free times. However, I don't see how I can get specific time for each day, because there's only a start time and an end time, but not time range within those days.

**Here's the current working code, where the $busy_obj contains the busy slots returned by the FreeBusy request.**

```
// ------------------
// This part
// includes all the elements
// to get the
// free time slots
// ------------------

// Range to search for open times in.

$first_day_xp = strtotime('today GMT'); //first day start
$last_day_xp = strtotime("2020-02-12T17:00:00.000Z"); //last day to fetch


$start_time = $first_day_xp; 
$end_time = $last_day_xp;

// Test data
$events = $busy_obj = array(
);


// Kick off first appt time at beginning of the day.
$appt_start_time = $start_time;

// Loop through each appt slot in the search range.
while ($appt_start_time < $end_time) {
    // Add 29:59 to the appt start time so we know where the appt will end.
    $appt_end_time = ($appt_start_time + 1799);

    // For each appt slot, loop through the current appts to see if it falls
    // in a slot that is already taken.
    $slot_available = true;
    foreach ($events as $event => $times) {
        $this_start = strtotime($times['start']);
        $this_end = strtotime($times['end']);

        // If the appt start time or appt end time falls on a current appt, slot is taken.
        if (($appt_start_time >= $this_start && $appt_start_time < $this_end) ||
            ($appt_end_time >= $this_start && $appt_end_time < $this_end)) {
            $slot_available = false;
            break; // No need to continue if it's taken.
        }
    }

    // If we made it through all appts and the slot is still available, it's an open slot.
    if ($slot_available) {
        $date = new DateTime();
        $date->setTimestamp($appt_start_time);
        $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));

        echo "Créneau disponible: ". $date->format("d-m-Y h:i:s-e") ."<br />";
    }

    $appt_duration = 120; //duration in minutes 

    // + 30 minutes
    $appt_start_time += (60 * $appt_duration);
}
```

### What I'm trying to do:

- group the output by date
- ask the output to only show slots with a start hour and end hour
  (only between 9AM and 6PM for example)

Here's the current output example (I removed some lines to make it shorter):

```
Créneau disponible: 09-02-2020 01:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 09-02-2020 03:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 09-02-2020 09:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 09-02-2020 11:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 10-02-2020 01:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 10-02-2020 03:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 10-02-2020 09:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 10-02-2020 11:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 10-02-2020 01:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 10-02-2020 03:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 10-02-2020 05:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 10-02-2020 07:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 10-02-2020 09:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 10-02-2020 11:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 11-02-2020 01:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 11-02-2020 03:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 11-02-2020 05:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 12-02-2020 01:00:00-Europe/Berlin
```

I've thought about using json to use the data more freely, however I'm not sure how to do that.

Thank you!

If it helps:
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35514097/google-calendar-api-algorithm-to-find-open-time-slots-for-a-given-day) for main SO with the freebusy request that helped get free slots

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question right. Do you want to print only the `$appt_start_time` that are after 9 am? Can you please try to explain a bit more in detial what else you want to implement?

Comment: The current output is
`Créneau disponible: 09-02-2020 01:00:00-Europe/Berlin
Créneau disponible: 09-02-2020 03:00:00-Europe/Berlin`
  
And I'm trying to make it like this:
`Créneau disponible: 09-02-2020
01:00:00
03:00:00`

So grouping time by date, and only showing times that are in a range. The issue is that if I do anything outside the loop it doesn't work, and I don't know how to properly use the output to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

- Your app has the variable `$appt_start_time` that increments value within each loop
- The length of each time slot is `$appt_duration = 120`
- Within your `if` statement you create a date object with the timestamp of `$appt_start_time` and `echo` it
- If apart from the start time, you also want to print the end time, you simply need to do add to the start time the time duration
- Since you have several slots and the `$appt_start_time` gets overwritten within each loop, you need to calculate and return the end time within each iteration - inside the `if` statement

Sample:

```php
if ($slot_available) {
        $date = new DateTime();
        $date->setTimestamp($appt_start_time);
        $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
        $date2 = new DateTime();
        $end_time = $appt_start_time + $appt_duration * 60;
        $date2->setTimestamp($end_time);
        $date2->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
        echo "Créneau disponible: ". $date->format("d-m-Y h:i:s-e") ."-".$date2->format("d-m-Y h:i:s-e")."<br />";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, however my issue is about the returned time that I need to have grouped for each day (Day 1 -> time 1, time 2 Instead of Day 1 -> time 1, Day 1 -> time2) and setting a time range for the loop for it to only show times within a range.